# performSelectorInBackground and MapKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkannotationview, mapkit

I am working with MapKit and annotations in iOS. Right before the annotations are added (which can take a while), I would like to display a small "Loading..." UIView. If I do this without threading, the loading view lags so much that it barely appears before it's dismissed. If I use performSelectorInBackground to load the annotations, it will work every few tries and the rest of the UIView will appear but no annotations, even though `mapView:didAddAnnotationViews:` is called. Can anyone think of why this would be behaving so unpredictably?

This is how I'm calling it, if it helps:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(refreshAnnos) withObject:nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the annotations on the background, but you should always ADD them on the main thread.

That is why

```
     mapView:didAddAnnotationViews:
```

is called, but does not propagate to the UI. It would be the same as calling the UITableViewDelegate methods in the background.

You could possibly try the following design pattern using GCD

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
       //Load the annotations on the background queue;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           //add the annotations to the mapView; 
        });
    });
```

Comment: +1, GCD is most often a better solution than `performSelectorInBackground`.

Comment: But note that `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND ` is only available since iOS 5. To support iOS 4 as well `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW` might be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

What do you do in `refreshAnnos`?

If you're adding the annotations to the mapview there, it will not work (because of the background thread). You need to update the mapview inside of the main thread.

Best,
Christian